# Add local image into an imageView

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimageview

I have been programming based on this youtube video guide and using the code provided in said videos (currently working at [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlzu_DXtG80)). The current lesson focuses on adding thumbnails that would be available online. However, my current goal is using local images as thumbnails since the few videos I would have would never change in my specific project.

Currently I have the following code. It works perfectly fine (as it's supposed to) with the line tagged as "LINE A":

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Project

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var videos:[Video] = [Video]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let model = VideoModel()
        self.videos = model.getVideos()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell")!

        //let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle

        //Customize the cell to display the video title
        //cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle

        //Construct the video thumbnail url

        //LINE A
        let videoThumbnailUrlString = "https://i.imgur.com/bYESnOo.jpg"

        //LINE B
        //let videoThumbnailUrlString = "/Users/User/Documents/Project/" + videos[indexPath.row].thumbnailId + ".JPG"

        //Create a NSURL object
        let videoThumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: videoThumbnailUrlString)

        if videoThumbnailUrl != nil {

            //Create a NSURLRequest object
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: videoThumbnailUrl!)

            //Create a NSURLSession
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            //Create a datatask and pass in the request
            let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        //Get a reference to the imageview element of the cell
                        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                        //Create an image object from the data and assign it into the imageView
                        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                    })

            })

            dataTask.resume()

        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

I tried using the line tagged as "LINE B", but it returns an error tagged as `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`
and below reading as `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrappin an Optional value (lldb)`

This is the Video class:

```
    import UIKit

class Video: NSObject {

    var videoId:String = ""
    var thumbnailId:String = ""
    var videoTitle:String = ""
    var videoDescription:String = ""
}
```

And the VideoModel class is the following:

```
//
//  VideoModel.swift

import UIKit

class VideoModel: NSObject {

    func getVideos() -> [Video] {

        var videos = [Video]()

        //Create video object
        let video1 = Video()
        //Assign properties
        video1.videoId = "_T-zq-aKha3"
        video1.thumbnailId = "1Alissa"
        video1.videoTitle = "Alissa"
        video1.videoDescription = "Tu vieja samurai comiendo un peanut butter jelly sandwich."

        //Append it into the videos array

        videos.append(video1)


        //Create video object
        let video2 = Video()
        //Assign properties
        video2.videoId = "LUabbwPd-4I"
        video2.thumbnailId = "2SettingGoals"
        video2.videoTitle = "Setting Goals"
        video2.videoDescription = "Rakatata y las mujeres donde estan auuuuu azucar."

        //Append it into the videos array

        videos.append(video2)


        //Create video object
        let video3 = Video()
        //Assign properties
        video3.videoId = "j1HTxdtE5Yg"
        video3.thumbnailId = "3Plan"
        video3.videoTitle = "Plan"
        video3.videoDescription = "Sancho panza se come un hotdog enrollado en 5 rodajas de pan con harta ketchup."

        //Append it into the videos array

        videos.append(video3)


        //Create video object
        let video4 = Video()
        //Assign properties
        video4.videoId = "7moB28WpcIg"
        video4.thumbnailId = "4AlissaSuges"
        video4.videoTitle = "Alissa's Suggestions"
        video4.videoDescription = "Sancho panza se come un hotdog enrollado en 5 rodajas de pan con harta ketchup."

        //Append it into the videos array

        videos.append(video4)

        return videos
    }

}
```

Any hint or clue in respect to how to achieve switching to local images would be appreciated.
If you need any other information from me, please feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Try this: `let videoThumbnailUrlString = "file://Users/User/Documents/Project/"`

Comment: @ryantxr same error happens

Comment: Take a look at all the places you are using ! to force unwrap a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to bind the cell to the tableview through `registerNib` or `registerClass` function. 
And one more thing, the function `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?` you used may return nil object. Its return value is `optional`. So you'd better use `if let` statement in case of it's nil and create a cell if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Project

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var videos:[Video] = [Video]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let model = VideoModel()
        self.videos = model.getVideos()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell")!

        //let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle

        //Customize the cell to display the video title
        //cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle

        //Construct the video thumbnail url

        //LINE A
        //let videoThumbnailUrlString = "https://i.imgur.com/bYESnOo.jpg"

        //LINE B
        let thumbnailId = videos[indexPath.row].thumbnailId 

             let videoThumbnailUrlString = "/Users/User/Documents/Project/" + thumbnailId + ".JPG" 

             //Create a NSURL object
             if let videoThumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: videoThumbnailUrlString) {

                 //Create a NSURLRequest object
                 let request = NSURLRequest(URL: videoThumbnailUrl)

                 //Create a NSURLSession
                 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                 //Create a datatask and pass in the request
                 let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                             //Get a reference to the imageview element of the cell
                             if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView {
                                   if let data = data {
                                       //Create an image object from the data and assign it into the imageView
                                       imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                    }

                               }

                         })

                 })

                 dataTask.resume()

        } else {
             print("\(videoThumbnailUrlString) is an invalid path")
        }


        return cell

    }
```

You should really avoid using forced optional wrappers (the `!` mark) or you may encounter this compiler complaint A LOT and not know what this issue is

Comment: The first `if let` is giving a syntax error that says: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Video'". As a newbie I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It gives a new error "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'String'".

Comment: Odd. Can you post your Video class for me?

Comment: Great. Easy.  I edited the code again omitting the first if let

Comment: I added the other classes for you to see. But in any case, it seems to work fine by omitting the first `if let`, the problem however persists. When debugging it, it takes the string file path fine but the app doesn't display any of the images. I noticed the values of `request`, `session` and `dataTask` don't change from their initial random addresses, perhaps it has to do with that?